# conflict between mathpazo and amssymb

Tags: mathpazo, amssymb

I like Palatino so I used mathpple. But it seems to be obsoleted. So I try to replace it with mathpazo. The problem is that I have the error message " too many's alphabets..."
When I remove amssymb, it works. But amssymb is great...
Any idea?

Edit:
The problem is more general. In the example when you remove only one of the package the problem disappears.

minimal example:

```latex
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,landscape,twocolumn]{article}

\usepackage[sc]{mathpazo}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{skull}
\usepackage{stmaryrd}
\usepackage{wasysym}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\DeclareSymbolFont{mathb}{U}{mathb}{m}{n}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Please tell us if you currently load `amssymb` before or after `mathpazo`. Incidentally, if you're worried about using obsolote or nearly-obsolete packages, don't bother with `mathpazo`. Instead, load the `newpxtext` and `newpxmath` packages. Note that they should be loaded *after* `amssymb`.

Comment: Can you provide a minimal example? I cannot reproduce this behaviour.

Comment: @Mico: I tried both, same result. But when trying to provide a minimal example I understood why you cannot reproduce this behavior Ralf. The problem is more general. In the example when you remove only one of the package the problem disappears.

Answer (score 6):

`mathpazo.sty` has

```latex
\DeclareSymbolFont{operators}     {OT1}{pplx}{m}{n}
\DeclareSymbolFont{upright}       {OT1}{zplm}{m}{n}
\DeclareSymbolFont{letters}       {OML}{zplm}{m}{it}
\DeclareSymbolFont{symbols}       {OMS}{zplm}{m}{n}
\DeclareSymbolFont{largesymbols}  {OMX}{zplm}{m}{n}
```

one more than the standard. Next `amssymb.sty` (actually `amsfonts.sty`) has

```latex
\DeclareSymbolFont{AMSa}{U}{msa}{m}{n}
\DeclareSymbolFont{AMSb}{U}{msb}{m}{n}
```

One more is declared by `skull.sty`

```latex
\DeclareSymbolFont{SKULL}{U}{skulls}{m}{n}
```

One more with `stmaryrd.sty`

```latex
\DeclareSymbolFont{stmry}{U}{stmry}{m}{n}
```

Next `wasysym.sty`

```latex
\DeclareSymbolFont{wasy}{U}{wasy}{m}{n}
```

Your declaration adds one more and the total is 11.

Now let's look at the math alphabets in `mathpazo.sty`

```latex
\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathit}     {OT1}{pplx}{m}{it}
\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathbf}     {OT1}{zplm}{b}{n}
\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathbold}   {OML}{zplm}{b}{it}
```

This brings the total to 14. Next `amssymb.sty` (better, `amsfonts.sty`):

```latex
\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathfrak}{U}{euf}{m}{n}
```

However, there are other math alphabets, namely `\mathsf` and `\mathtt`, which `siunitx` triggers the loading of. This makes 17: too many.

What can you do? You can easily avoid wasting a math group for `skull`. If you load `amsmath` (you should anyway), you can replace `\usepackage{skull}` with

```latex
\DeclareFontFamily{U}{skulls}{}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{skulls}{m}{n}{ <-> skull }{}
\DeclareSymbolFont{SKULL}{U}{skulls}{m}{n}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\skull}{\text{\usefont{U}{skulls}{m}{n}\symbol{'101}}}
```

Avoiding the dreaded symbol altogether would be better.

Also, `\DeclareSymbolFont{mathb}{U}{mathb}{m}{n}` does nothing at all and indeed you receive a message saying that `U/cmr/m/n` is used.

Comment: Thanks, I use \DeclareSymbolFont{mathb}{U}{mathb}{m}{n} because without it \DeclareMathSymbol{\Earth}{3}{mathb}{"43} don't work. I load amsmath but I left in the example only package which produce the error.

Comment: @entr0pie Just one symbol can be dealt with the method I suggested for `\skull`.

Comment: Don't understand, I did as you said for \skull but I'm going to erase it because I never use it. I prefer use \bcattention. However I use wasysym only for one symbol which is \astrosun.

Answer (score 4):

In the modern toolchain, you can load an OpenType font based on Palatino and completely remove this problem.

```
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\defaultfontfeatures{Scale = MatchLowercase}
\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Pagella}
\setmathfont{Asana Math}
```

This requires LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX, and includes all symbols from `mathpazo`, `amssymb`, and most other packages you include.  Any modern math font will have more symbols and more consistency than any combination of legacy packages.

You could replace TeX Gyre Pagella with Palatino Linotype or Palatino if you have them, or Asana Math with TeX Gyre Pagella Math.

If you want to continue to use legacy font packages, you can replace both `mathpazo` and `amssymb` with the newer `newpxmath`, then load either `tgpagella` or `newpxtext` as your main font.  There are the options `nosymbolsc` and `noamssymbols` to free up math alphabets.